# BigCommerce Get Orders by Min Date Created

Tags: c#, json, api, bigcommerce

I am having issues trying to access orders by the min_date_created.

Here is some sample data from the orders.json. Note: the formatting might not be 100% correct because I took out a lot of irrelevant data

```
[{"id":341,"customer_id":0,"date_created":"Fri, 16 Nov 2012 21:43:32 +0000","date_modified":"Mon, 25 Nov 2013 13:43:44 +0000","date_shipped":"","status_id":1,"status":"Pending"},

{"id":342,"customer_id":0,"date_created":"Fri, 16 Nov 2012 21:43:32 +0000","date_modified":"Mon, 25 Nov 2013 13:43:46 +0000"}]
```

I use this URL (I have taken out some of the values for privacy):

```
https://xxxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/orders.json?min_date_created=Thu, 15 Nov 2012 21:43:32 +0000
```

Formatted with the %20 for spaces I get this...

```
https://xxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/orders.json?min_date_created=Thu,%2015%20Nov%202012%2021:43:32%20+0000
```

Everything I can see looks fine... But when I submit the request I get 500 Internal Server Error and there is no data displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your min_date_created is not properly URL encoded, `,` and `:` were not URL encode.

It would look like `Wed%2C%2015%20May%202013%2005%3A30%3A00%20%2B0000`.